# Have library zkSforce for android?

Tags: android, salesforce, android-support-library

i have used zkSforce library for IOS but now i want use for android because c panel created in saleforce so i don't have library and any solution for this. Please provide me any hint or solution.
Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main options

1) Mobile SDK for Android, see https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android this provides a wrapper for the Salesforce REST API and includes pre-canned implementations of the OAuth login flows etc.

2) WSC see https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc is primarily a java soap stack and wraps the Salesforce SOAP APIs (this is the same API that ZKSforce wraps). This should be usable on Android, but provides nothing Android specific.

I'd recommend (1) unless you have specific requirements to call the SOAP API.